# How does IBM Message Hub count and bill for partitions created

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

According to Bluemix, IBM Message hub is billed based on (a) "number of partitions created (calculated daily)" and (b) the number of messages sent.  Each partition created, it says, costs $10.

In our case, we have unit tests which execute multiple times a day, to make sure our code that creates and deletes partitions works properly.  Each time the unit test runs, a partition is created and then deleted.

If my unit test runs 10 times a day, but deletes every partition it creates, will I be charged $100/day?  Or will I be charged $0 because I always cleaned up after myself?

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

we frequently sample the number of partitions used.
So if you always create 1 and then delete it, you will be charged at most for one.

HTH

Comment: Well the partition names created are always unique, though they are always deleted within a few seconds of creation.  So I guess I need to know, if I run my unit test 100 times, are you saying I might get charged $1,000?

Comment: Mike, the name of the partition is not used, we sample the count of partitions only. If every time the sample runs we find you have 100 partitions then you will be charged $1,000. 
If any time we sample we find you have 1 - you will be charged $10.

Comment: Perfect.  Then one last question.  I trust I will only be charged _once_ for a given partition?  That is, if I create one partition and never create another partition, I will be charged $10, but next time the sampler runs, finding that same partition, it will somehow remember I've already been charged for it, right?

Comment: yes :-) it doesn't matter that it finds the _same_ partition, if every time it runs it finds you have one partition, you will be charged $10 per month.